# How to omit all the last elements of a numpy ndarray in python?

Tags: python, numpy

So I can slice a numpy array quite simply as:

```
a = np.arange(10)
a[:-3]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

but now say I do:

```
a = np.vstack((a, a))
a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Is there a nice pythonic way (without looping) to get:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Slice along `axis=1` : `a[:,:-3]`?

Comment: cool thanks knew it would be simple, was trying a[:][:-3] and getting nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Divakar in comments.

```
a[:,:-3]
```